# Can not fetch submodule using glide

Tags: go, azure-sdk

https://github.com/Masterminds/glide

I try to use glide with Azure go sdk.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go

In this repository, it uses submodule.

I create a simple glide.yaml like this.

```
package: cf-engine
import:
- package: github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go
```

then

```
glide install
```

However, the submodule directory(storage) still empty. 
I tried

```
glide update --all-dependencies
```

Also it is still the empty.

I tried go get. Then the submodule directory was filled.

```
 go get github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go
```

How can I fetch the submodule directory using glide?

Comment: What is the output of `glide list` ?

Comment: Just reading the docs, it appears (correct me if I'm wrong) glide doesn't actually install to the normal `pkg` directory, but to the `vendor` directory in your app directory.